# Creating Application for other enterprise to SSO and list directory users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, saml, google-workspace, passport-saml

I am trying to create a web application. This app is a B2B PAS model.
One of the features of the app is, an organization using GSuite, can onboard our system and then all its users can log in to our software using their org's google ids. However, in the application, one user can assign task to another user in org. So our application should be able to list all users of the org too.

How can both these features be achieved?

I have tried the SAML approach, by creating a custom app from Gsuite admin console. However, can SAML be extended to also list users from the organizations which the SAML app belongs to? (Basically trying to use the [Google Cloud Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory))

What other alternative approaches should I look for if pure SAML doesn't work out?

P.S tech stack I'm using is Nest JS for backend and Angular for frontend

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding properly you are looking for the way to populate all users/ID from  organization to your  SAML App. Single sign-on (SSO) allows users to sign in to enterprise cloud applications using their managed Google account credentials, more details here in [set up your own custom SAML application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en). It is also possible to [Set up SSO using 3rd party IdPs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en).

However, Google supports several industry standard protocols like OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect 1.0 and SAML 2.0 for handling authentication, authorization, and single sign-on. You can take a look at [authenticating corporate users in a hybrid environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authenticating-corporate-users-in-a-hybrid-environment) for more details.